# Factoring Polynomial exercise in ruby, unexpected syntax?

Tags: ruby, math, syntax

I got these errors --

```
(eval):30: (eval):30: compile error (SyntaxError)
(eval):8: syntax error, unexpected kDO
```

-- when I ran this ruby code in console --

```
class Factor
    puts "This program will factor a polynomial in the form of \"Ax^2 + Bx + C.\""

    aPos = PosOrNeg?("A")

    # test
    puts aPos

    def PosOrNeg?(string = "blank") do
        puts "Tell us if \"#{string}\" is positive or negative. Type \"pos\" or \"neg\"."
        posOrNegStr = gets.chomp
        case posOrNegStr
        when "pos"
            pos = true
        when aPosOrNegStr = false
            pos = false
        else
            while posOrNegStr != "pos" && posOrNegStr != "neg" do
                puts "Invalid input. Please type \"pos\" or \"neg\"."
                posOrNegStr = gets.chomp
                case posOrNegStr
                when "pos"
                    pos = true
                when aPosOrNegStr = false
                    pos = false
                else
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Remove `do` from line: `def PosOrNeg?(string = "blank")` and then try

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It's worth noting that Ruby methods and variables should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` convention. Using capital letters is unusual and, as you can see here, confuses the syntax highlighter.

Answer (score 3):

Look at lines:

```
# test
puts aPos

def PosOrNeg?(string = "blank") do # <- here!!
```

Here's an ideal syntax for defining a method in Ruby:

```
def method_name
  # method body
end
```

So, change `def PosOrNeg?(string = "blank") do` to `def PosOrNeg?(string = "blank")`.

Note: In Ruby the coding style for defining a method or an object is **snake_cased**, which is pretty famous among the Ruby community. It'd be much better if you name your method to be something like: `pos_or_neg?(string = 'blank')`.

Comment: Thanks all of you! I'm very new to Ruby (coming from Java, as you may have figured by my camel casing).

Comment: @DanielBaskin: Welcome to Ruby community. Please accept answer if it helped you(that's famous in SO community for saying thanks). Also, I guess CamelCase is pretty famous coding style in JavaScript community as well. :)